# Where does Air Force One refuel?

Tags: fuel, boeing-747, refueling, us-air-force, mid-air-refueling

Obama came to Greece and then to Germany. That's a long trip, even for the majestic Jumbo. There was a lot of discussion about where the aircraft was refuelled during that trip. Do we know, in general, where Air Force One is refueled?

There were claims that it was refuelled in the air by American aircraft, but isn't that more costly than refuelling on the ground?

Comment: Relevant: after Germany, they headed to Lima, Peru, a distance too far to fly without refueling. As such, they [landed at Lajes Air Base, Azores](http://chicago.suntimes.com/news/obama-guidance-press-schedule-nov-18-2016-berlin-lima-peru/) for a brief stop to refuel, then proceeded to Lima.

Comment: @ZachLipton a "a United States Air Force detachment unit", as [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lajes_Field) mentions.

Comment: To add a last note to the answers: Mid air refuelling is dangerous. You don't want to to it with a president onboard unless you have a VERY good reason to do so.

Comment: Note: technically speaking, "Air Force One" is the callsign of *any* Air Force aircraft while the president is on-board, and *only* while the president is on board. The two VC-25As *are* equipped for mid-air refueling, and I am guessing, they sometimes *do* refuel in mid-air, but according to the quote in [@ymb1's answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33309/3721), they *never* refuel in mid-air with the president on board, which means never when they are actually acting as "Air Force One".

Comment: Presumably they could fly both jets (which gives some ambiguity as to which one he's actually on), refuel the one he's not on, and then move him to the jet that's full when it's on the ground. Though that seems a little convoluted for typical circumstances!

Comment: I think they should re-fuel the one that he's not on, and then transfer him to the other one in mid-air.  http://www.historyinsidepictures.com/siteimages/AIR%20B11.JPG

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the *Washington Post,* Air Force One never refueled in mid-air with the president on board.

If it needs to refuel, it usually does so at one of the U.S. military bases across the world.

> The retrofitted Boeing 747 that usually serves as the presidential jet can indeed refuel in flight — but it has never done so with the president on board, military officials say.
>
> It has enough range to fly from Washington to Iraq without needing more fuel. On longer trips to Asia, it typically stops at U.S. military bases in Alaska or Germany.
>
> — [Five myths about presidential travel](http://wpo.st/joeF2)

Comment: As a Greek citizen I can confirm the fact with the military bases . . . :)

Answer (score 24):

I can't confirm whether either VC-25 has refueled in flight while acting as AF1 but the aircraft is so equipped for the job.

I do know refueling on the ground depends on where the jet is and the quantity and quality of fuel available onsite.  The USAF insists on using fuel that it supplies for security reasons.  For operations in Western Europe the fuel  is trucked in from nearby military bases.  When the jet visits more remote nations such as in Africa or Asia, fuel is flown out to the jet in fuel trucks loaded aboard C-17s.  Strangely enough, this is really how it works!

Comment: I was stationed at Hickam AFB, Hawaii, during a Presidential trip to Asia, and detailed to assist during the layover to refuel *both* VC-25s.  (Yep, always bring a spare jumbo jet when flying overseas ;)  The fuel for the planes was loaded onto refueling trucks in advance, and after it was tested the trucks were kept under special guard on the flightline to ensure it wasn't tampered with.